# Search api solr create a custom search link

Tags: search

I try to create a custom search link like this :

```
l(t('See our Job Ads'), 'search', array('query' => array('f[0]' => 'is_recruiter_nid:' . $nid )));
```

when i click on the link nothing get filtered.
P.S : i have added the filter '`is_recruiter_nid`' in code using the `hook_search_api_solr_documents_alter()` Something like:

```
function MYMODULE_search_api_solr_documents_alter(array &$documents, SearchApiIndex $index, array $items) {
  foreach ($documents as $document) {
     ...
     $document->setField('is_recruiter_nid', $recruiter->nid);    
  }
}
```

How I can do this? Is there any example ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

f[0] param doesn't work directly. To allow ApacheSolr to filter results based on custom fields you will need to define them as facet (checkout [FacetAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi) module) or you can implement `hook_apachesolr_query_alter` and add your own filters in it.

Comment: I'm not using the apachesolr module but "search api solr". thanks for your reply.

Comment: You can try [hook_search_api_solr_query_alter](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!search_api_solr!search_api_solr.api.php/function/hook_search_api_solr_query_alter/7). If this hook doesn't work try few other hooks from [search_api_solr api](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21search_api_solr%21search_api_solr.api.php/7)